# Stuck at this error "RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu"

Tags: python, pytorch

I am running the following code. If I try to run it on CPU only it runs fine but it takes too much time to train. So I thought to change the runtime to GPU and made appropriate changes. Now it is stuck.

```
import torch
from models.bert_attention_model import AttentionModel
from models.bert_cnn_model import BERTCNNSentiment

import sys

if sys.argv[1].lower() =="hinglish":
  data_path = "../data/hinglish/"
elif sys.argv[1].lower() == "spanglish":
  data_path = "../data/spanglish/"
else:
  print("Format: %s %s" %(argv[0], argv[1]))

train_name = "train.txt"
test_name = "test.txt"
model_save_names = ["../checkpoint/cnn_model.txt", "../checkpoint/attention_model.txt"]




import random
import numpy as np

SEED = 1234

random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

from transformers import BertTokenizer, AutoTokenizer, XLMRobertaTokenizer

tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base")
print('XLM Roberta Tokenizer Loaded...')



init_token_idx = tokenizer.cls_token_id
eos_token_idx = tokenizer.sep_token_id
pad_token_idx = tokenizer.pad_token_id
unk_token_idx = tokenizer.unk_token_id

max_input_length = 150
print("Max input length: %d" %(max_input_length))

def tokenize_and_cut(sentence):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence) 
    tokens = tokens[:max_input_length-2]
    return tokens




from torchtext import data

UID = data.Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False, pad_token=None)
TEXT = data.Field(batch_first = True,
                  use_vocab = False,
                  tokenize = tokenize_and_cut,
                  preprocessing = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids,
                  init_token = init_token_idx,
                  eos_token = eos_token_idx,
                  pad_token = pad_token_idx,
                  unk_token = unk_token_idx)


LABEL = data.LabelField()

from torchtext import datasets

fields = [('uid',UID),('text', TEXT),('label', LABEL)]
train_data, test_data = data.TabularDataset.splits(
                                        path = data_path,
                                        train = train_name,
                                        test = test_name,
                                        format = 'tsv',
                                        fields = fields,
                                        skip_header = True)
train_data, valid_data = train_data.split(random_state = random.seed(SEED))
print('Data loading complete')
print(f"Number of training examples: {len(train_data)}")
print(f"Number of validation examples: {len(valid_data)}")
print(f"Number of test examples: {len(test_data)}")


tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(vars(train_data.examples[0])['text'])



LABEL.build_vocab(train_data, valid_data)


print(LABEL.vocab.stoi)




BATCH_SIZE = 128

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print("Device in use:",device)
train_iterator, valid_iterator, test_iterator = data.BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data, test_data),
    sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text), 
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
    device = device)

print('Iterators created')

print('Downloading XLM Roberta model...')

from transformers import XLMRobertaModel
bert = XLMRobertaModel.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base')

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
print('XLM Roberta model downloaded')


OUTPUT_DIM = 3
DROPOUT = 0.3
N_FILTERS = 100
FILTER_SIZES = [2,3,4]
HIDDEN_DIM = 100

model_names = ["CNN_Model", "Attention_Model"]
models = [  BERTCNNSentiment(bert, OUTPUT_DIM, DROPOUT, N_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZES),
            AttentionModel(bert, BATCH_SIZE, OUTPUT_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, 50000, 768)  ]



def count_parameters(model):
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

for i in range(2):
    print(f'The {models[i]} has {count_parameters(models[i]):,} trainable parameters')

for i in range(2):
    print("Parameters for " + f'{model_names[i]}')
    for name, param in models[i].named_parameters():                
        if param.requires_grad:
            print(name)

import torch.optim as optim
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
def clip_gradient(model, clip_value):
    params = list(filter(lambda p: p.grad is not None, model.parameters()))
    for p in params:
        p.grad.data.clamp_(-clip_value, clip_value)

optimizers = [optim.Adam(models[0].parameters()), optim.Adam(models[1].parameters())]


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
nll_loss = nn.NLLLoss()
log_softmax = nn.LogSoftmax()



for i in range(2):
    models[i] = models[i].to(device)
criterion = criterion.to(device)
nll_loss = nll_loss.to(device)
log_softmax = log_softmax.to(device)



from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def categorical_accuracy(preds, y):
    count0,count1,count2 = torch.zeros(1),torch.zeros(1),torch.zeros(1)
    count0 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
    count1 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
    count2 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
    total0,total1,total2 = torch.FloatTensor(1),torch.FloatTensor(1),torch.FloatTensor(1)
    max_preds = preds.argmax(dim = 1, keepdim = True) # get the index of the max probability
    correct = max_preds.squeeze(1).eq(y)
    predictions = max_preds.squeeze(1)
    true_correct = [0,0,0]
    for j,i in enumerate(y.cpu().numpy()):
      true_correct[y.cpu().numpy()[j]]+=1
      if i==0:
        count0+=correct[j]
        total0+=1
      elif i==1:
        count1+=correct[j]
        total1+=1
      elif i==2:
        count2+=correct[j]
      else:
        total2+=1
    metric=torch.FloatTensor([count0/true_correct[0],count1/true_correct[1],count2/true_correct[2],f1_score(y.cpu().numpy(),predictions.cpu().numpy(),average='macro')])
    return correct.sum() / torch.FloatTensor([y.shape[0]]),metric,confusion_matrix(y.cpu().numpy(),max_preds.cpu().numpy())



def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, i):
    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    
    model.train()
    
    for batch in iterator:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        if (i == 0):
          predictions =  model(batch.text).squeeze(1)
        else:
          predictions =  model(batch.text, batch_size = len(batch)).squeeze(1)
            
        loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)

        acc,_,_ = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
        
        loss.backward()
        clip_gradient(model, 1e-1)
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
        
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)


def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion, i):
    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    epoch_all_acc = torch.FloatTensor([0,0,0,0])
    confusion_mat = torch.zeros((3,3))
    confusion_mat_temp = torch.zeros((3,3))

    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
    
        for batch in iterator:
            if (i == 0):
              predictions = model(batch.text).squeeze(1)
            else:
              predictions = model(batch.text,batch_size=len(batch)).squeeze(1)
            
            loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
            
            acc,all_acc,confusion_mat_temp = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_acc += acc.item()
            epoch_all_acc += all_acc
            confusion_mat+=confusion_mat_temp
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator),epoch_all_acc/len(iterator),confusion_mat


import time

def epoch_time(start_time, end_time):
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    elapsed_mins = int(elapsed_time / 60)
    elapsed_secs = int(elapsed_time - (elapsed_mins * 60))
    return elapsed_mins, elapsed_secs


N_EPOCHS = 40

best_f1 = [-1, -1]
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    for i in range(2):
        start_time = time.time()
        
        train_loss, train_acc = train(models[i], train_iterator, optimizers[i], criterion, i)
        valid_loss, valid_acc,tot,conf = evaluate(models[i], valid_iterator, criterion, i)
        f1 = tot[3]
        end_time = time.time()

        epoch_mins, epoch_secs = epoch_time(start_time, end_time)
        
        if f1 > best_f1[i]:
            best_f1[i] = f1
            
            path = model_save_names[i]
            print(path)
            torch.save(models[i].state_dict(), path)
        
        
        print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Epoch Time: {epoch_mins}m {epoch_secs}s')
        print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
        print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')
        print(tot)
        print(conf)

for i in range(2):
    path = model_save_names[i]
    models[i].load_state_dict(torch.load(path))


def ensemble_evaluate(models, iterator, criterion):
    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    epoch_all_acc = torch.FloatTensor([0,0,0,0])
    models[0].eval()
    models[1].eval()
    confusion_mat = torch.zeros((3,3))
    confusion_mat_temp = torch.zeros((3,3))
    
    with torch.no_grad():
    
        for batch in iterator:
          
          predictions0 = models[0](batch.text).squeeze(1)
          predictions1 = models[1](batch.text, batch_size=len(batch)).squeeze(1)
          
          predictions = F.softmax(predictions0, dim=1) * F.softmax(predictions1, dim=1)
          loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
          
          acc,all_acc,confusion_mat_temp = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
          epoch_loss += loss.item()
          epoch_acc += acc.item()
          epoch_all_acc += all_acc
          confusion_mat += confusion_mat_temp
    print(confusion_mat)
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator),epoch_all_acc/len(iterator)


def ensemble_write_to_file(models, test_iterator):
    label_dict = {'0':'negative', '1':'neutral', '2':'positive'}
    file = open("answer.txt", "w")
    file.write('Uid,Sentiment\n')
    count = 0
    for batch in test_iterator:
      predictions0 = models[0](batch.text).squeeze(1)
      predictions1 = models[1](batch.text, batch_size=len(batch)).squeeze(1)
      predictions = F.softmax(predictions0, dim=1) * F.softmax(predictions1, dim=1)
      max_preds = predictions.argmax(dim = 1, keepdim = True).detach().cpu().numpy()
      for i,row in enumerate(batch.uid.cpu().numpy()):
        count += 1
        label_number = max_preds[i][0]
        label_number_str = list(LABEL.vocab.stoi.keys())[list(LABEL.vocab.stoi.values()).index(label_number)]
        predicted_label_name = label_dict[label_number_str]
        if count != len(test_data):
          file.write('%s,%s\n'%(row,predicted_label_name))
        else:
          file.write('%s,%s'%(row,predicted_label_name))
    file.close()

valid_loss, valid_acc, tot = ensemble_evaluate(models, test_iterator, criterion)
print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')
print(tot)
```

Here is the output which is I am getting. I have shown only the requird output necessary for debugging

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 268, in <module>
    train_loss, train_acc = train(models[i], train_iterator, optimizers[i], criterion, i)
  File "main.py", line 212, in train
    acc,_,_ = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
  File "main.py", line 184, in categorical_accuracy
    count1+=correct[j]
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

Can someone tell me where to make the appropriate changes so that the code may run on the GPU in Google Colab.

Edit_1:
Thank you so much for the help you provided it actually solved my problem, but now a similar new problem arised. Note that I have updated the code to include the changes you mentioned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 271, in <module>
    train_loss, train_acc = train(models[i], train_iterator, optimizers[i], criterion, i)
  File "main.py", line 215, in train
    acc,_,_ = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
  File "main.py", line 194, in categorical_accuracy
    return correct.sum() / torch.FloatTensor([y.shape[0]]),metric,confusion_matrix(y.cpu().numpy(),max_preds.cpu().numpy())
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is exactly as the error says, Pytorch expects all operations to be done in the same device but the two tensors you are adding are in different places.

You need to add `.to(device)` to these variables

```
    count0,count1,count2 = torch.zeros(1),torch.zeros(1),torch.zeros(1)
```

Like

```
count0 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
count1 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
count2 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
```

But just in case if there is `NameError: name 'device' is not defined` you can just use the `y`'s or `pred`'s device like

```
device = y.device

count0 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
count1 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
count2 = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
```

Comment: Please look at the edit in the question for the reply

Comment: After making some more changes on my own following your reply, I was able to get my script run on the GPU. Thank you so much for the help. Please ignore the edit in the question.